# Transition between xaml pages in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am working in VB.net in VS2012 with store template and I want to make transition between two XAML pages with animation when I press a button.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are no built in Page transitions, however, you can use a `ContentThemeTransition` to transition the content of a `ContentControl`, see [this blog post](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/10/winrt-transitions-creating-fast-and-fluid-metro-uis/) for an example.

Comment: Hello,thank you for replying but this isn't quite what I need. I am working with Windows 8 and I have 2 xaml pages one is mainpage in which I have a button. I want to make transition to registration page when clicked.